# Overflow issue when using mudblazor blazor hybrid

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, mudblazor, blazor-hybrid

This code has an overflow issue. Please look right upper corner and end of tab panel. Couldn't able to find the error. Can anyone suggest a solution. I used mudbalzor as a library. going to implement a blazor hybrid app for tabs.

```cs
<MudGrid Justify="Justify.Center">

    <MudAppBar Style="background-color:#053B71;color:white;width:contain" Fixed="false" Dense="false" DisableGutters="false" Class="mt-2">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" Class="ml-2" />
        <MudText Class="ml-4" Style="font-weight:800;font-size:large">BLX Super Mart</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Logout" Style="color:white;background-color:aqua" Href="/" Class="ml-2" />
    </MudAppBar>

    <MudGrid >
        <MudItem xs="7" Style="background-color:yellow">
            <MudTabs Elevation="2" Rounded="true" PanelClass="pa-6" PrevIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.SkipPrevious" NextIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.SkipNext"
                     AlwaysShowScrollButtons="true" Color="@Color.Primary" Style="border:thin;border-color:darkgray;border-radius:10px">
                @foreach (string category in tabscat)
                {
                    <MudTabPanel Text=@category ToolTip="Choose a Category" OnClick="() => LoadItems(category)"  >
                        <MudGrid>
                            @foreach (var item in tabscatitm)
                            {

                            }
                        </MudGrid>
                    </MudTabPanel>
                }
           </MudTabs>
       </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the exception details? The stack trace?

Comment: Where can I get the exception details??

Comment: Sorry, I misleading "overflow issue"... Forget my precedent question.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try move you `MudAppBar` outside of the main `MudGrid` and use the `MudLayout` component

```html
<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Style="background-color:#053B71;color:white;width:contain" Fixed="false" Dense="false" DisableGutters="false" Class="mt-2">
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" Class="ml-2" />
        <MudText Class="ml-4" Style="font-weight:800;font-size:large">BLX Super Mart</MudText>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Logout" Style="color:white;background-color:aqua" Href="/" Class="ml-2" />
    </MudAppBar>

    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Medium">
            <MudGrid Justify="Justify.Center">
                <MudGrid>
                    <MudItem xs="7" Style="background-color:yellow">
                        <MudTabs Elevation="2" Rounded="true" PanelClass="pa-6" PrevIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.SkipPrevious" NextIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.SkipNext"
                                AlwaysShowScrollButtons="true" Color="@Color.Primary" Style="border:thin;border-color:darkgray;border-radius:10px">
                                <MudTabPanel Text="AAAA" ToolTip="Choose a Category"  >
                                    <MudGrid>
                                    </MudGrid>
                                </MudTabPanel>
                                <MudTabPanel Text="BBBB" ToolTip="Choose a Category"  >
                                    <MudGrid>
                                    </MudGrid>
                                </MudTabPanel>
                                <MudTabPanel Text="CCCC" ToolTip="Choose a Category"  >
                                    <MudGrid>
                                    </MudGrid>
                                </MudTabPanel>                                        
                        </MudTabs>
                    </MudItem>
                </MudGrid>
            </MudGrid>
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/camducPHecwyvTIz